# What do you call an object oriented syntax that uses discrete syntactic building blocks as opposed to long descriptive function names?

Tags: syntax

I am just wondering if there is a classification/name that differentiates these different programming styles. In all cases we have a Car Class.

```
car = Car()

# Long descriptive function that takes object as parameter
d = getWheelDiameterForCar(car)
```

vs

```
# medium length descriptive function that is a method of a car
d = car.getWheelDiameter()
```

vs

```
# short method names that returns component objects
d = car.wheels()[0].diameter().value()
```

Comment: Some would argue that the last example is "a violation of the Law of Demeter".  There are also concepts similar to the last one that are called "a fluent interface", though I'm not sure that example demonstrates it.  That would be something where each method returns the object itself, or something semantically comparable, such that methods can be chained to form a kind of semantic sentence describing the operation.  Like LINQ in C#, jOOQ in Java, etc.

Comment: The law of demeter is not really a law and its can be an overly proscriptive dogma at times. I appreciate its goals but i think the last case above can be very useful for a flexible domain specific syntax where the coupling of the syntax mimics the natural coupling of the objects being interacted with.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a specific term for the first couple of examples, but the 3rd example I believe is known as a Fluent Interface for a Domain Specific Language.